# Basic Brainfuck interpreter (part 2)

Tags: python, python-2.x, interpreter, brainfuck

I have this obsession with esoteric programming languages. So I decided to spiff up my [previous Brainfuck interpreter](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/58071/basic-brainfuck-interpreter).

```
# Simple BrainF*** interpreter

# Class that stores lang variables
class Lang(object):
    step = 0
    cell = [0] * 30000
    test_cell = [0] * 30000
    pos = 0
    test_pos = 0
    loop = False
    loop_ret = 0


# Main interpreter function
def interpreter():

    code_input = raw_input('Code: ')
    steps = len(code_input)

    while Lang.step < steps:

        if code_input[Lang.step] == '+':
            Lang.cell[Lang.pos] += 1

        elif code_input[Lang.step] == '-': 
            Lang.cell[Lang.pos] -= 1

        elif code_input[Lang.step] == '>':
            if Lang.pos < 30000:
                Lang.pos += 1
            elif Lang.pos > 30000:
                Lang.pos = 0

        elif code_input[Lang.step] == '<':
            if Lang.pos > 0:
                Lang.cell_pos -= 1
            elif Lang.pos < 0:
                Lang.pos = 30000

        elif code_input[Lang.step] == '[':
            if Lang.loop == False:
                Lang.loop_ret = Lang.step
                Lang.loop = True

        elif code_input[Lang.step] == ']':
            if Lang.cell[Lang.pos] != 0:
                Lang.step = Lang.loop_ret
            elif Lang.cell[Lang.pos] == 0:
                Lang.loop = False

        elif code_input[Lang.step] == '.':
            print str(chr(Lang.cell[Lang.pos]))

        elif code_input[Lang.step] == ',':
            Lang.cell[Lang.pos] = int(raw_input())

        elif code_input[Lang.step] == ":":
            Lang.test_cell[Lang.test_pos] += 1

        elif code_input[Lang.step] == ";":
            Lang.test_cell[Lang.test_pos] -= 1

        elif code_input[Lang.step] == "}":
            if Lang.test_pos > 30000:
                Lang.test_pos += 1
            elif Lang.test_pos < 30000:
                Lang.test_pos = 0

        elif code_input[Lang.step] == "{":
            if Lang.test_pos > 0:
                Lang.test_pos -= 1
            elif Lang.test_pos < 0:
                Lang.test_pos = 30000

        elif code_input[Lang.step] == "$":
            if Lang.test_cell[Lang.test_pos] == Lang.cell[Lang.pos]:
                print True 
            elif Lang.test_cell[Lang.test_pos] != Lang.cell[Lang.pos]:
                print False 

        Lang.step += 1


# Running the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    interpreter()
```

If there are any issues, please mention them. All I'm looking for is any general improvements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a word: **dictionaries**.

You have a class that only has class attributes and lacks any methods; that could just be a dictionary:

```
lang = dict(
    step = 0,
    cell = [0] * 30000,
    test_cell = [0] * 30000,
    pos = 0,
    test_pos = 0,
    loop = False,
    loop_ret = 0
)
```

*(Alternatively, if you really want attribute (`foo.bar`) rather than key (`foo['bar']`) access to the values, look into [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields).)*

You have a whole bunch of `elif`s; that could also be a dictionary (with some judiciously-named functions):

```
commands = {
    "+": increment_byte,
    "-": decrement_byte,
    ...
}
```

This makes your `interpreter` loop:

```
def interpreter():

    lang = dict(...)
    commands = {...}

    code_input = raw_input('Code: ')    
    steps = len(code_input)

    while lang['step'] < steps:           
        command = code_input[lang['step']]
        if command in commands:
            commands[command](lang)    
        lang['step'] += 1
```

along with e.g.:

```
def increment_byte(lang):
    """Increment the byte at the data pointer."""
    val = lang['cell'][lang['pos']]
    lang['cell'][lang['pos']] = ((val + 1) % 256)
```

*(Note use of `%` per @user50399's answer.)*

This has two advantages:

- very simple loop in `interpreter`; and
- `commands` acts as a syntax guide (covering @Dagg's comment).

---

You could also add some input validation:

```
def accept_input(lang):
    """Accept one char of input, storing its value in the byte at the data pointer."""
    while True:
        try:
            i = ord(raw_input("Enter char: "))
        except TypeError:
            pass
        else:
            if i in range(256):
                lang['cell'][lang['pos']] = i
                break
        print("Not a valid input.")
```

*(Note switch to `ord` per @user50399's answer.)*

Answer (score 4):

You haven't implemented the language properly.

Nested loops are ignored.  This makes it impossible to implement a large class of Brainfuck programs.  It's hard enough to write Brainfuck programs even without this handicap.

The output routine incorrectly appends a newline to every character it prints.

The input routine incorrectly expects a string rather than a single character, and incorrectly parses the string as a number rather than extracting the character's ASCII code.

Your support for circular memory tape is wrong.

- If `Lang.pos = 29999` and the `>` command is encountered, then `Lang.pos = 30000`.  Suppose you try a `+` operation then — that's an `IndexError`.
- If `Lang.pos = 30000` and the `>` command is encountered, the pointer doesn't move.  That also makes the `elif` branch unreachable.
- Analogous bugs exist for the `<` command.  By the way, Python automatically wraps negative array indices for you anyway: `Lang.cell[-1]` is the last element of the list.

It's odd that `interpreter()` is a standalone function rather than a member of the `Lang` class.  Also, why call the class `Lang`, when you could name it `BrainfuckInterpreter`?

You have implemented the [non-wrapping dialect](http://esolangs.org/wiki/brainfuck#Memory_and_wrapping) of Brainfuck.  The original language treats each cell as an unsigned byte, doing all calculations modulo 256.